# 2 Cross Products?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, cross-product

Usually, if we want to find the cross product of 2 vectors $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$, we want to find the vector which is perpendicular to both of them. Let's say the cross product of $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ is $\vec{d}$. Isn't $-\vec{d}$ then also perpendicular to $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$? Does that mean that there are 2 cross products, or am I making a mistake?

Comment: The cross product is not **defined** as a vector perpendicular to the two vectors (because, as you noted, there are two such vectors). Rather, it's a convenient feature of it. You have to take the order into account, as $\vec a \times \vec b \neq \vec b \times \vec a$.

Comment: @MattiP. The cross product **can** be defined as being perpendicular to the two vectors, so long as you include the right hand rule to ensure the definition is sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cross product of $\vec b$ and $\vec c$ is defined as the vector with the following properties:

1. The length of the product is equal to $|\vec b|\cdot|\vec c|\cdot\sin(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is the angle between the two vectors.
2. The product is perpendicular to both $\vec b$ and $\vec c$.
3. The direction of the product is such that it follows the right hand rule.

The last point ensures that the cross product is uniquelly defined by $b$ and $c$. That is, of the *two* vectors that satisfy points 1 and 2, only one of them satisfies point 3

---

Note that there are many interpretations of the right hand rule, from (literally) hand-wavy ones, to (for the purpose of this question) circular ones (i.e., one way to define the right hand rule would be to say that it is **defined** by the direction of the cross product).

Let's strike a balance then and define the right hand rule as such:

> If $\vec a \times \vec b=\vec c$, then, looking onto the plane, spanned by $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ from the **positive** side (i.e., from the side into which $\vec c$ *points into*), the angle required to rotate $\vec a$ into $\vec b$ is **smaller** than the angle required to rotate $\vec b$ into $\vec a$.